# How Insert the values of all the fields into a variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I really would appreciate your help for the following problem; I need to create a stored procedure, which accepts two parameters:

```
@TableName    
@KeyField
```

I need to store them into 1 variable where the values are separated by `|`

For example the Customers table is as follows;

```
CustomerID     CustomerName         City

111            Adventure            Boston

222             Pubs                 NY
```

And I execute  `EXEC mysp  'Customers', 111`

**I need to return the following result format:**
`@ReturnValue = 111|Adventure|Boston`

Here is my stored proc;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my sp

@table varchar

@key   numeric

AS

@field varchar(40),

@object int


Select @object = object_id from systables where name =@table

--The instructions to create a cursor

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )


Select @object  = name from sys.columns where object_id = @object

--The instructions to close and deallocate the cursor

--I have already to save the value using the EXEC command but is not working; something like

@String = Select @object from @table where CustomerID = @keyValue
```

Can you please help me,

Thanks

Comment: What is **CustomerID** in `Select @object from @table where CustomerID = @keyValue`. Why it is specified? This also need to be passed as a parameter. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jesuraja that you will need the name of the key column as parameter ... if you can live with that you could try something like this ...

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = 'Customers'
declare @keyfieldName nvarchar(max) = 'CustomerId'
declare @keyfieldValue int = 111

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = convert(nvarchar(max), 
    (select (select 'isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), ' + c.name + '), '''') + '' | '' + ')
        from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
        where t.name = @tablename for xml path('')))
set @sql = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 9) + ' FROM ' + @tablename + 
            ' WHERE ' + @keyfieldName + ' = @keyfieldValue'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@keyfieldValue as int', @keyfieldValue
```